# Aptana Studio 3.4.0 Cmd-F only works once

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana, eclipse-juno

I routinely download the latest 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' and add Aptana Studio to it.  I recently did this with Juno 4.2.2 and Aptana Studio 3.4.0.  Now, I find that in the html or css editors, the cmd-f key still brings up the find/replace bar once.  But when I ESCape out of that find bar, the cmd-f command no longer works until I switch to another editor window and then return to the first one.  Then, cmd-f works, but again only one more time.  The 'Edit-->Find/Replace menu item works consistently', so I think it has something to do with key bindings.

I also tried downloading the standalone Aptana Studio 3.4.0 and it doesn't have this issue.

Never had this problem before.  Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here with Aptana nightly, as well as FDT, so this might be a general eclipse problem. Also same thing with F3, so it's not only the find function.

Answer (score 1):

Me too. Its super annoying since I use Aptana all day.

**Workaround:** You can work around it by **disabling the Aptana Find Bar** in Preferences and restart Eclipse (this means you have to use the default Eclipse search dialog). Just move it out of the way while you're searching. If you disable it and go back to the old Eclipse search, you also get the ability to use the keyboard shortcuts for the items under the "Commands" menu.

Here's an aptana ticket for this bug: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7850